# Hexadecimal to Binary in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, binary, hex

I have a program that takes the user input of an IOS text field and converts it into binary, hex, dec etc. I have been unable to implement an algorithm that convert Hexadecimal directly to binary without recursion. Any suggestions how to do this? 
This is what I have tried but it really doesn't work

```
 NSString *theNumber = [display text];
 NSMutableString *str = @"";
        for(NSInteger numberCopy = theNumber; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>= 1)
        {

           display.text = glGetString;[((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Not being unkind, but you need to **read the compiler warnings**. `NSString *theNumber` and `NSInteger numberCopy = theNumber` is not going to do anything remotely sensible and the compiler slaps a warning on this line. It also warns on the previous line `NSMutableString *str = @""`. Obj-C inherits a lax type system from C(++), but the Obj-C compiler does its best to check your program for you. Somebody has done your (home?)work for you, but really you should read those warnings and figure out why your code makes no sense. That's my "fishing rod", rather than "fish", for the day :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSString*)hexToBinary:(NSString*)hexString {
    NSMutableString *retnString = [NSMutableString string];
    for(int i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i++) {
        char c = [[hexString lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:i];

        switch(c) {
            case '0': [retnString appendString:@"0000"]; break;
            case '1': [retnString appendString:@"0001"]; break;
            case '2': [retnString appendString:@"0010"]; break;
            case '3': [retnString appendString:@"0011"]; break;
            case '4': [retnString appendString:@"0100"]; break;
            case '5': [retnString appendString:@"0101"]; break;
            case '6': [retnString appendString:@"0110"]; break;
            case '7': [retnString appendString:@"0111"]; break;
            case '8': [retnString appendString:@"1000"]; break;
            case '9': [retnString appendString:@"1001"]; break;
            case 'a': [retnString appendString:@"1010"]; break;
            case 'b': [retnString appendString:@"1011"]; break;
            case 'c': [retnString appendString:@"1100"]; break;
            case 'd': [retnString appendString:@"1101"]; break;
            case 'e': [retnString appendString:@"1110"]; break;
            case 'f': [retnString appendString:@"1111"]; break;
            default : break;
        }
    }

    return retnString;
}
```

This method does no verifying to ensure the passed string is actually a pure hex string, so that's something you may want to consider.

---

Alternatively, there's this option:

```
- (NSString*)hexToBinary:(NSString*)hexString {
    NSMutableString *retnString = [hexString mutableCopy];

    [retnString replaceOccurencesOfString:@"0"
                               withString:@"0000"
                                  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0,[retnString length])];
    // repeat all the way through, much like above example

    return retnString;
}
```

The first example is certainly cleaner, I think.  I'm not certain which example would be faster.